# Kinect SDK with Silverlight instead of WPF?

Tags: silverlight, kinect

I would like to know if anyone has any experience using Kinect SDK 1.0 with Silverlight.

I am aware that there are posts on the internet showing it can be done. However, the posts I have found are dated before the official SDK was realised.

I guess my question really boils down to this: Is it as simple as installing the SDK and adding the reference to the silverlight project just like you would with a WPF project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. The Kinect SDK only works in the full .NET framework (or native C++).

You can make it work with Silverlight using SL Trusted applications with Interop access (P/Invoke, etc). For more info see this for example:

http://mosalem.blogspot.com.br/2011/09/silverlight-5-p-invoke-using-kinect-sdk.html

http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect/SilverLight-5-and-Kinect-via-the-magic-of-P-Invoke

Although those use the beta, the method would be the same with the 1.0 SDK.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - exactly what I wanted to know. And that's a shame, I guess I will have to look into P-Invoke.

Comment: Glad to help! Although there's absolutely no reason IMO to use Silverlight OOB full trust and P/Invoke instead of WPF. What would be your scenario?

Comment: I was curious because it would be nice if my application could be embedded into a website, rather than downloading a WPF application. But I have decided to go with WPF in the end anyway. And the scenario is creating a 'virtual wardrobe' application.

Comment: I believe you have chosen the best choice for some reasons (besides the P/Invoke):
1. No 3D support on Silverlight in-browser (except with elevated trust, which you shouldn't expect on the web)
2. When you have a web app, people expect it will work in different OS and environments (e.g. without Kinect). Since it won't, there's no reason not to offer your app for download.